# Time complexity for recursive binary search that also prints current subarray

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, binary-search

Find the total running time of the following code in big O notation. The input array is sorted with size n.

```c
int print (int array[], int low, int high, int x) {     
    int mid = (high + low) / 2;
    if (low > high)
        return -1;      // cannot find x in the array
    if (array[mid] == x)
        return mid;     // x is found
    if (array[mid] > x) {
        for (int i = low; i < mid; i++)
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        return print(array, low, mid – 1, x);
    }
    if (array[mid] < x) {
        for (int i = mid + 1; i <= high; i++)
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        return print(array, mid + 1, high, x);
    }
}
```

The recursive part is the same as binary search, so I know the time for that part is O(log n). The program prints out every element for the subarray that may contain the query x, so can I say the running time for that line is O(n)? And the total running time of the code is simply O(n)?

Is the recursive part O(log n) affecting the total running time?

Comment: The `print` inside the for statements should obviously be `printf`.

Comment: At each step, the interval cuts in half, so if there are 16 elements, on average you'll print 8, then 4, then 2, then 1.  That would be O(n).

Comment: But my classmate said why isn't like O(nlogn), like the running time of the printf line should be (n/2)*log n = O(nlogn) @TimRoberts

Comment: Using `printf` for generating output makes the output size dependent on the number of digits in each number in the array. On the other hand, if we should regard this as C code with fixed sized `int` data type, then this is not relevant. It would be relevant in a language like Python, where the `int` type is a dynamic "big" integer data type. Is your question about C?

Comment: @trincot This is a pseudocode for analysing the running time, so the syntax probably not affecting the answer I guess

Comment: @TimRoberts Your first comment seems wrong. `print` is the name of the recursive function

Comment: If this is pseudo code, then is there a limit on the values in the array? Are they supposed to be 64bit values, or can they be *any* integers with *any* number of decimal digits?

Comment: ah... see that now. So the comment is just not valid anymore

Comment: @SupportUkraine he is right, the `print` function called recursively in `return` statement.

Comment: @trincot the question only mentioned that the input is an n-size array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output concerns the subarray that is about to be used for the recursive call. So each output concerns the half of the current window, which halves at each recursive call. This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), and the sum has a closed formula, which in this case is bounded by  (as we start the series with  /2). So in total, O() array values are printed (and as many spaces).

There are now two scenarios to distinguish:

1. This is pseudocode and there is no limit on how large the integers are: in that case printing a single value is not O(1): it takes O(1) time to print one digit. It takes more time to print an integer that has 50 digits than an integer with just 2 digits. So then the time complexity is O(), where  is the average (or maximum) number of digits for an integer in the input array. We could also say it is O(log), where  is the maximum value in the array, or the negated minimum value in the array, whichever is greater (as there could be negative values).

   For example, if the array would be equal to [1,2,3,..,] then =, and the complexity O(log).
2. The `int` data type represents a **fixed size** data type (like 64-bit), and so we know the decimal representation of such integers has a fixed ceiling on the number of digits they can have. In that case the effort of printing an integer is O(1), and the overall complexity is O().

Comment: Is that mean even I am not sure about the running time for the recursive function, I can still get the answer O(n)? Also, the running time for line `return print(array, low, mid – 1, x);` is it also n/2?

Comment: @propigisme, it depends on whether this is about fixed-size integers or unbound integers, as I have explained in my answer. If you don't know, then in your place I would ask whomever gave the assignment. It is a legit question for clarification to ask them. The running time for the recursive calls is included in the analysis.